# Python: How to escape a lot of CSS in string.format()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Python's

```
 string.format()
```

function can ignore CSS if double brackets are used instead of one.

```
string = '''
         .b{{padding:1px;}}
         .c{{padding:2px;}}
         .d{{padding:3px;}}
        '''
```

but what do you do when you have too much CSS ?

Do I have go go trough each one of them and make them double brackets?

I prefer not to load my CSS file via:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/test.css">
```

because it gets cached and so on. I place it in the html directly.

Comment: even changing the css file (name) randomly has a lack of logic associated with it because ultimately it might not get loaded before the html does in a certain manner.

Comment: If you know for certain that the CSS doesn't contain anything you want to format (as you would if you wanted to replace all the braces with doubles), why are you using `.format` on the string at all? If your goal is to emit HTML with the CSS included, call `.format` on the html first and then add the CSS afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Double braces is your only option.

If your concern is centered on a caching issue, may I suggest

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/test.css?[randomly_generated_number]">
```

where you replace [randomly_generated_number] with, well, some random number. That would prevent caching for that file.